# "Document is not Defined"

Tags: javascript, loops, document

New to JavaScript and I'm having a hard time trying to resolve this problem. Thank you so much

```
var attempts = 0;
var randomNumber;

while (randomNumber === 10) {
    randomNumber = (Math.random(10 - 1) + 1);
    attempts = attempts + 1;
}

document.write("It took " + attempts + " attempts");
```

Comment: its work why undefined? what you try to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be included in an HTML snippet since you are calling on `document` object. The document object represents your web page. If you want to access any element in an HTML page, you always start with accessing the document object.

For, example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
var attempts = 0;
var randomNumber;

while (randomNumber === 10) {
    randomNumber = (Math.random(10 - 1) + 1);
    attempts = attempts + 1;
}

document.write("It took " + attempts + " attempts");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Being new that just gave me a ton of really useful info i can apply to other things. Thanks !